# sqlite3 не работает

Tags: sqlite3

Привет в терминале powershell на запрос sqlite3 выдает такую ошибку

```
sqlite3 : Имя "sqlite3" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность напис
ания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:1
+ sqlite3
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (sqlite3:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

кто знает в чем проблема?

Цитата

Comment: sqlite3 не установлен или не прописан в переменной окружения PATH. C django это никак не связано.

Comment: Файл у меня есть db.sqlite3 в папке а дальше не чего не понимаю что надо делать,так как внятно не кто не может обьяснять.

Comment: Чтобы запускать команду sqlite3, нужен где-то файл sqlite3.exe, просто файла базы не достаточно. Вам нужно [отсюда](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) скачать "A bundle of command-line tools for managing SQLite database files, including the command-line shell program, the sqldiff.exe program, and the sqlite3_analyzer.exe program." (в разделе Precompiled Binaries for Windows). Скачать, распаковать куда-то. Можно в принципе в папку проекта, но добавлять это в гит не нужно. Или в отдельную папку, потом добавить эту папку в переменную окружения PATH (гуглится как это сделать).

Comment: Да я тут разобралась,теперь у меня проблемы с Postgrest) что это значит?   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'service.apps.ServiceConfigweb_lib'; 'service.apps' is not a package

Comment: Без понятия, не сталкивался с такой ошибкой. Может postgres криво установлен.

Comment: Ошибку я нашла в настройках но теперь появилась такая ошибка,    TypeError: 'class Meta' got invalid attribute(s): verbase_name,verbase_name_plural,TYPES,id,name,age,email,lit_tupe